$\iint_Re^{x^2-y^2}dA$, where $R$ is enclosed by $x^2-y^2=1$, $x^2-y^2=16$, and $x=2y$.

Evaluate $\iint_Re^{x^2-y^2}dA$, where $R$ is a region in the first quadrant, enclosed by the curves $x^2-y^2=1$, $x^2-y^2=16$, and $x=2y$.

I tried change of variables using Jacobian: Let $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=\dfrac xy$, we have $u\in[1,16]$ and $v\in[0,2]$.
$$
J'=\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 2x & -2y \\  \dfrac1y & \dfrac{-x}{y^2} \end{vmatrix}=\dfrac{-2x^2}{y^2}+2=2(1-v^2)$$
So $J=\dfrac1 {2(1-v^2)}$, where $J$ should be non-negative. As $v\in[0,2]$, I divided the interval into $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. The integral is,
$$\iint_R e^{x^2-y^2}dA=\int_1^{16}\int_0^1\dfrac{e^u}{2(1-v^2)}dvdu+\int_1^{16}\int_1^2\dfrac{-e^u}{2(1-v^2)}dvdu$$
Starting from $\int_0^1\dfrac1{2(1-v^2)}dv$ I got $\dfrac14\ln\left|\dfrac{1-v}{1+v}\right|$. When I substitute the upper bound (which is $1$), I get $\infty$. I'm not sure how to continue.

Edit:
Using @Bob Dobbs's comment I found my mistake. Here is the corrected answer:
Let $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=\dfrac yx$, we have $u\in[1,16]$ and $v\in[0,1/2]$.
$$
J'=\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 2x & -2y \\  \dfrac{-y}{x^2} & \dfrac{1}{x} \end{vmatrix}=2-\dfrac{2y^2}{x^2}=2(1-v^2)$$
So $J=\dfrac1 {2(1-v^2)}$. The integral is
$$\iint_R e^{x^2-y^2}dA=\int_1^{16}\int_0^{1/2}\dfrac{e^u}{2(1-v^2)}dvdu=\int_1^{16}\dfrac14\ln\left|\dfrac{1+v}{1-v}\right|e^u\vert^{v=1/2}_{v=0} du$$
$$=\dfrac14\ln(3)e^u\vert^{16}_1=\dfrac14\ln(3)(e^{16}-e)$$

Should it be that $v=\frac yx$?

@BobDobbs Oh, now I see my mistake. First quadrants implies, $y=0$ and not $x=0$.

I think that $v\in[2,\infty).$
New Edit: I meant $v=\frac xy$ is fine too.
Notice the region is bounded from below by the line $y=0$ which is $x$-axis. The boundry $x=2y$ is maped to $\frac xy=v=2.$ Where is the boundry $y=0$ mapped to on $uv$-plane? Consider the lines, $x=Ny$, $N\geq 2$ combing the given region. The line $x=Ny$ is mapped to $v=N$. Since $y=0$ is the limit of $x=Ny$ when $N\to+\infty$, $y=0$ is mapped to $+\infty$ in the extended $uv$-plane. Hence,
$$\iint_R e^{x^2-y^2}dA=\int_1^{16}\int_\infty^2\dfrac{e^u}{2(1-v^2)}dvdu=\frac14(e^{16}-e)\ln3$$
